Keep getting this Error: Unable to access jarfile pepk.jar in my React-Native app
I'm trying to publish my app using google play console, it seems they have changed the way you sign your app:

I downloaded the encryption public key and added it to the app folder which also contains the pollit.keystore file.
I then downloaded and added the pepk.jar file in my JAVA_HOME location:
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17\bin

But when I try to call:
java -jar pepk.jar --keystore=pollit.keystore --alias=foo --output=pollit.zip --include-cert --rsa-aes-encryption --encryption-key-path=encryption_public_key.pem

I get this error:
Error: Unable to access jarfile pepk.jar

Does anyone know how to solve this?
if I try and access the pepk.jar file from another folder:
java -jar C:\Users\tp_re\Downloads\pepk.jar --keystore=pollit.keystore --alias=foo --output=pollit.zip --include-cert --rsa-aes-encryption --encryption-key-path=encryption_public_key.pem

I get this error:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/google/wireless/android/vending/developer/signing/tools/extern/export/ExportEncryptedPrivateKeyTool has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 55.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0

This is my setup in android studio, could it be because of my JDK version:

My Java Version:

Update

I changed my JDK to 20, I got closer but still another error:

